# Doing Operations in Matrix

Tags: matrices

This is a simple question that I'm trying to understand.

***if A and B are 3×3 and B=(b1, b2, b3), then AB=(Ab1+Ab2+Ab3)***

I envisioned A and B to be like so:
$$ A = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    * & * & * \\
    * & * & * \\
    * & * & * \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$ B = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    * & * & * \\
    * & * & * \\
    * & * & * \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

It was given to me that B=(b1, b2, b3). I'm assuming this is from the first row of the matrix.

The final answer of AB is supposed to be AB=(Ab1+Ab2+Ab3). This cannot be right because you cannot add the products Ab1, Ab2, and Ab3. Instead, it should be AB=(Ab1 Ab2 Ab3) right? Not sure if I explained this right.

Comment: If $b_1,b_2,b_3$ are column vectors in $B$ then $AB = (Ab_1,Ab_2,Ab_3).$ Otherwise, I don't see how to interpret it.

Comment: That's what I was thinking kind of with AB=(Ab1 Ab2 Ab3) instead of AB=(Ab1+Ab2+Ab3). I found this question confusing when I first got it. I interpreted it completely wrong and thought B=(b1, b2, b3) was the actual matrix and argued that it didn't have the same dimensions as described. Simple mistake on my end.

Comment: If $B$ is a column vector then $AB  = A\begin {bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix} = a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3$ where $(a_1,a_2, a_3)$ are the column vectors of $A$